# Same Array Elements

Tags: java, arrays

I want to check if all the elements in one array is the same as all the elements in another array, ie, one to one match. (NB: the two array elements will not be in the same order as each other)

Is there a quick way of doing this, or a pre-existing library I can use?

Currently the two ways I can think of is not pretty:

**match one by one** *(Edit 3: this example is wrong, doesn't cater for duplicates)*

```
    boolean exactMatch = true;
    if(strList1.size() == strList2.size()){
        for(String str: StrList1){
            if(!strList2.contains(str)){
                exactMatch = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

**sort then match** (more optimised, esp for large arrays)

```
    strList1 = Arrays.sort(strList1);
    strList2 = Arrays.sort(strList2);

    boolean exactMatch = true;
    if(strList1.size() == strList2.size()){
        for (int i = 0; i < strList1.length; i++) {
            if(!strList1[i].equals(strList2[i])){
                exactMatch = false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Edit 1**

Thanks for those who has given comments. The array elements are not in the same order as each other. ie, the following will return false:

```
String[] strList1 = {"ABC", "CDE", "EFG"};
String[] strList2 = {"ABC", "EFG", "CDE"};
System.out.println("array equals " + Arrays.deepEquals(strList1, strList2));
```

---

**Edit 2**

One good point I left out which 'myusuf' pointed out is the matter of duplicates in the array.
This means that my "Match One By One" example will not work. Take this for example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strList1 = {"ABC", "CDE", "EFG", "ABC"};
    String[] strList2 = {"ABC", "EFG", "CDE", "CDE"};
    System.out.println(arrayEquals(strList1,strList2));
}
private static boolean arrayEquals(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
    List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(array1);
    List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(array2);
    return list1.containsAll(list2) && list2.containsAll(list1);
}
```

In this case, strList1 has a duplicate for "ABC" and strList2 has a duplicate for "CDE", but they still match because their unique elements are still the same, when the array it self is different.

---

**Edit 3**

Thanks everyone that have answered.
So after a lot of back and forth, it seems the shortest way to do it is:

```
    String[] strList1 = {"ABC", "CDE", "EFG", "CDE", "EFG"};
    String[] strList2 = {"ABC", "EFG", "CDE", "EFG", "CDE"};

    Arrays.sort(strList1);
    Arrays.sort(strList2);
    boolean exactMatch = Arrays.deepEquals(strList1, strList2);

    System.out.println("test3 - match: " + exactMatch);
```

I was hoping for one method call that could do it all, but it seems there is done.
Arrays.deepEquals() only works with sorted arrays if all elements are different in order.
The approach with contains() does not work as there are duplicates.

Comment: What about duplicate elements?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Comment: Do the arrays have duplicate elements? Like "CDE" occurring twice in List1 ?

Comment: Yes it should cater for duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a short solution of your problem. I am sure there are more performant but complicated methods to do it. Here `arrayEquals` transforms your arrays into a `List` and uses `List.containsAll` to check equality.

```
public class ArrayEquality {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] array1 = {"test1","test2"};
        String[] array2 = {"test2","test1"};
        String[] array3 = {"test2","test3"};

        String[] strList1 = {"ABC", "CDE", "EFG"};
        String[] strList2 = {"ABC", "EFG", "CDE"};

        System.out.println(arrayEquals(array1,array2));
        System.out.println(arrayEquals(array2,array3));

        System.out.println(arrayEquals(strList1,strList2));
    }

    //ARRAY EQUALITY CHECK
    private static boolean arrayEquals(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
        List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(array1);
        List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(array2);

        return list1.containsAll(list2) && list2.containsAll(list1);
    }
}
```

To deal with duplicates within this solution arrayEquals could be changed like this

```
private static boolean arrayEquals(String[] array1, String[] array2) {
List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(array1);
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(array2);

Collections.sort (list1);
Collections.sort (list2);
return list1.equals(list2);
}
```

One could optimise it by size checking to avoid sorting.

Comment: left out the question of duplication all together, please see edited question.

Comment: Updated my answer to consider question of duplication. By the way the first design was intentionally because you checked not for duplications (list.contains) in your examples.

Comment: almost there. A equals on an array will compare it's address. You will need to have a Arrays.deepEquals()

Comment: Could you give an example? I am using List.equals. This makes an equality check for every pair. This does exactly what we want because Strings are not checked by adress but by content. ("1" + "1").equals("11") == true  Or did I missunderstood your comment?

Comment: Ah, yes you are right, it works since you convert it into a List object.

Answer (score 1):

```
Arrays#deepEquals(java.lang.Object[], java.lang.Object[])
```

It provides the two array references are considered deeply equal or not.

```
Arrays.deepEquals(e1,e2);
```

> Two possibly null elements e1 and e2 are deeply equal if any of the
>   following conditions hold:
>
> ```
>  - e1 and e2 are both arrays of object reference types, and
>    Arrays.deepEquals(e1, e2) would return true
>  - e1 and e2 are arrays of the same primitive type, and the appropriate
>    overloading of Arrays.equals(e1, e2) would return true.
>  - e1 == e2
>  - e1.equals(e2) would return true.
>
> Note that this definition permits null elements at any depth.
> ```

[Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

Unlike the `Arrays#equals(Object[],Object[])` method, this method is appropriate for use with nested arrays of arbitrary depth.

Comment: array elements are not in the same order as each other.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Arrays.equals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29):

```
Arrays.equals(ary, ary2));
```

Or [Arrays.deepEquals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepEquals%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29)

> Returns true if the two specified arrays are *deeply equal* to one
> another. Unlike the `@link{#equals{Object[],Object[])` method, this
> method is appropriate for use with nested arrays of arbitrary depth.
>
> Two array references are considered deeply equal if both are `null`,
> or if they refer to arrays that contain the same number of elements
> and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are deeply
> equal.
>
> Two possibly `null` elements `e1` and `e2` are deeply equal if any of
> the following conditions hold:
>
> - `e1` and `e2` are both arrays of object reference types, and `Arrays.deepEquals(e1, e2)` would return true
> - `e1` and `e2` are arrays of the same primitive type, and the appropriate overloading of `Arrays.equals(e1, e2)` would return true.
> - `e1 == e2`
> - `e1.equals(e2)` would return true.

Comment: the array elements are not in the same order as each other.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static boolean equals(int[] a, int[] a2)
```

Returns true if the two specified arrays of ints are equal to one another. Two arrays are considered equal if both arrays contain the same number of elements, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two arrays are equal. In other words, two arrays are equal if they contain the same elements in the same order. Also, two array references are considered equal if both are null.

Comment: they two array elements are not in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list [removeAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29) method

```
strList2.removeAll(strList1)

if(strList2.isEmpty)
{
  // Exact match
}
else{

  // failed
}
```

Comment: that's a nice out of the box way of doing it. would be a bit hard on performance though.

Comment: That is wrong. If strList2 is a subset of strList1 then strList2.removeAll(strList1) would result in an empty list but that is definitily not an exact match.

Comment: @wumpz : i hope OP is not looking for an exact match from his sample code if(!strList2.contains(str)){
                exactMatch = false;
                break;
            } , just he is checking contains only.

Comment: Ah, good point wumpz. Yes I'm looking for an exact match. Because I'm making the size() check earlier, so I'm only doing contains from strList2 to strList1. Having said that though, you did raise one good point which is the matter of having duplicates in the array list. I'm going to explore this a bit further.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash Map. This method has lower time complexity as no sorting and searching is required, but higher space complexity as hash map is used:

```
        String[] strList1 = {"ABC", "CDE", "EFG"};
        String[] strList2 = {"ABC", "EFG", "CDE"};
        Boolean flag = true;
        Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        /*Initial Check*/

        if(strList1.length != strList2.length) {
           System.out.print("Array equals: false");
           return 0;
        }

        /*Add all strings from list1 and their frequency to map*/

        for(int i=0; i<strList1.length;i++) {
            if(map.get(strList1[i]) != null) 
               map.put(strList1[i], map.get(strList1[i]) + 1);
            else
               map.put(strList1[i], 0); 
        }

        /*If string found in map from list2, decrement count in map
          else list2 contains a string not in map, then arrays 
          unequal as list2 contains a string not in list1*/

        for(int i=0; i<strList2.length;i++) {
            if(map.get(strList2[i]) != null)
               map.put(strList2[i], map.get(strList2[i]) - 1);
            else {  
                System.out.print("Array equals: false");
                flag = false;
            }
        }

        /*If map contains the same value for every string i.e. 0, then they occur
          equal no. of times in both arrays. Hence, Set values will contain 
          only one value so (values.size() == 1) will be equal true, else false*/

        if(flag) {
            Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<Integer>(map.values());
            System.out.print("Array equals: " + (values.size() == 1));
        }
        return 0;
```

For your input, this would output: `Array equals: true`.
This method also takes into account duplicate strings in input arrays.

Comment: well done for spotting the duplication issue. Good effort on the example and I can see it working. Though I'm looking for something with less coding, and more use of provided libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following for this:

```
String[] strArray1;
String[] strArray2;
```

I renamed them to `strArray` instead of `strList` for logicalness, then:

```
private <T> boolean containsAll(final T[] a1, final T[] a2) {
    return Arrays.asList(a1).containsAll(Arrays.asList(a2));
}
```

and call it with:

```
boolean exactMath = containsAll(strArray1, strArray2) 
        && containsAll(strArray2, strArray1);
```

Please note that `Arrays.asList(T[] array)` just creates a `List<T>` **wrapper** around the `T[] array`, it does not actually make a copy of `T[] array`. If you modify the `List<T>`, it will **also** modify the backing `T[] array`.

Comment: left out the question of duplication all together, please see edited question.